# The shadow of the child element is clipped

Tags: html

I use the slider https://idangero.us/swiper/

My problem is that the shadow is clipped
[image]
I want the shadow not to be cropped
[image]
What should I do in order to make the shadow not cut off?

Comment: Adding some fiddle/ code would be easy to help

Comment: why don't you try { overflow : visible } Css property to your parent element